# Image does not fit to background image

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a page using bootstrap and css where when a mouse pointer is placed on an image, the image will fade and the background image will show. Image fades fine but does not fit though all of them is 100px in size(in all dimensons) and white space is seen.Link:http://codepen.io/Ishtiaque/pen/ONPRyp?editors=1100
 Here is my code:

```
<div class="portfolio">
  <h2>Portfolio</h2>
  <div class="row position">
    <div id="project1" class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3617441/376416154/stock-vector-phonebook-icon-phonebook-icon-eps-phonebook-icon-vector-phonebook-icon-eps-phonebook-icon-jpg-376416154.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="project1" class="col-xs-6">
      <img src="http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3617441/376416154/stock-vector-phonebook-icon-phonebook-icon-eps-phonebook-icon-vector-phonebook-icon-eps-phonebook-icon-jpg-376416154.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
#project1 {
  background-image: url("https://t1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/33/60/96/160_F_33609643_L3xInzQroBP4PX8zaZICZqofvvfRxZW9.jpg");
  background-size: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#project1 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

#project1 img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.portfolio {
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: url(http://4k-background.com/highresolution/l_011.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}

.position {
  padding-left: 70px;
}
```

[image: what i mean]

Comment: It's allways best if you include a working sample..

Comment: I do **not** know `bootstrap`, but something like this could work: [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h7Lmx37d/1/) (padding of the grid does create these spacings).
A grid row shouldn't be used directly for `background` as you did. Again, not sure if this is 'good' according to the `bootstrap` rules.

Comment: sorry i did not understand, pls explain @miguelmpn

Comment: Check the answer I just updated, that'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweaked with ur codepen and fixed it, there was padding on the div in the background. I set `padding: 0px;` and its good now.

**CSS**

```
#project1{

background-image:url("https://t1.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/33/60/96/160_F_33609643_L3xInzQroBP4PX8zaZICZqofvvfRxZW9.jpg");
background-size: cover;
padding: 0px;
}

#project1 {
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
#project1 img:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
.portfolio{
    padding-top:50px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:url(http://4k-background.com/highresolution/l_011.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    height:500px;
}
.position{
    padding-left:70px;
}

.image {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Just replace your CSS with this.

EDIT: Oh, by the way, add the `class="image"` to both image tags

Comment: tried adding background-size: cover; to the #project1 img{} tag 
still the white spaces does not go

Comment: can you upload a fiddle?

Comment: sorry i am new to this, what is fiddle?

Comment: No problem, post all your code in here https://jsfiddle.net/ and save it and comment the URL. it's to let others tweak the code to find a solution faster

Comment: i am doing my code here. It is similar to jsfiddle.
http://codepen.io/Ishtiaque/pen/ONPRyp?editors=1100

Comment: Ok, so what exactly are you trying to achieve, to just remove the white space?